# What is the purpose of ww1 prefixes on some domains

Tags: subdomain

Occasionally I see some websites with **ww1** prefix/subdomain instead of **www**.

Is there a designated use for subdomains such as ww1 and ww2?

Comment: Even `www.` isn't designated.  It's just a widely used convention.

Comment: It seems to be used with some (redirection based) load balancing/mirroring  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692273/why-ww2-sub-domains confirms my observations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've found that compromised domains Typically get prefixed ww1. instead of www. There seems to be a pattern to this, so I think ww1 Domains are compromised domains which were re-directed to a clean website domain, or websites which aren't quite through the CSS Page Layout and Deign process.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this?  It would be helpful to confirm.